# NativeQuery, join and Limit

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using "NativeQuery" with Doctrine and my query has an INNER JOIN. I want to do "Limit" with only the first table for the results. But, In Mysql, "Limit" takes into account joined tables. Any idea on how to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: I think it'd be easier to answer your question if you could add an example of your current query and what would be an expected outcome of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for Doctrine Pagination. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

here is an example with QueryBuilder you can adapt it to you own usage

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

$qb
  ->join('a.advert', 'adv')
  ->addSelect('adv')
;


$qb->setMaxResults($limit);


return $qb
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult()
  ;
```

you've said you are french here is a good tutorial 
[Récupérer ses entités avec Doctrine2](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/recuperer-ses-entites-avec-doctrine2)